# android - using dataBinding, on Activity instead of layout

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-android, android-databinding, rx-java2

I am working in MVVM design pattern.
I want to use dataBinding or RXJava in order to notify the View when the model has changed.
dataBinding can do it inside **xml**.
but i want to notify the **Activity** on a change in the model and do something  more complicated.
let's assume i want my TextView to change color when text in not empty.
can you help me to do it via dataBinding or RXJava ?

here is my code:

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="edi.com.mydatabindingsimple.MyViewModel" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@={viewModel.txt}" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@={viewModel.txt}" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity

```
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import edi.com.mydatabindingsimple.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            final ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
            binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

viewModel

```
    import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
import android.databinding.Bindable;



public class MyViewModel extends BaseObservable{
    private String txt;

    @Bindable
    public String getTxt() {
        return txt;
    }

    public void setTxt(String txt) {
        this.txt = txt;
        notifyPropertyChanged(edi.com.mydatabindingsimple.BR.txt);
    }

}
```

Comment: *but i want to notify the Activity on a change in the model and do something more complicated.*. Why the Activity? The VM get the changes and notify the properties. That should be all. If the binding is not *natively* supported you can use `@BindingAdapter` to add your own

Comment: thank you for the answer  Blackbelt.
I read about @BindingAdapter and realized it can only be used in a setter.
but i need it in a getter.
in case i want some boolean flag in my model which tells me to show/hide a View

Comment: so add `android:background="@{viewModel.textViewColor}"` in your `<TextView>` and add `@Bindable int getTextViewColor()` method in `MyViewModel`

Comment: @pspink, thank you for the answer
but i don't want to do it in xml directly.
of course it will work on this specific case,
 but if i want my viewModel to tell the View to be visible without knowing the constant number of View.Visible i will expect the Activity to deal with it.

Comment: so some view properties you want to set in xml / presenter / view-model (like `android:text`) and some (like `android:background`) via activity? does it make sense? but of course you can still call `viewModel.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(...)` inside `MainActivity#onCreate`, so now, when your text changes the callback is called in your activity, but... after adding the callback your view model has a reference to the activity. which is something you would like to avoid...

Comment: @pskink 
i agree that it doesn'y make sense,
but what can i do in case of complex UI change(like: hiding a key board)?  
i cannot do it by changing an xml attribute, but i still don't want to create a call back, which means adding a reference to Activty and "breaking" the MVVM architecture.

Comment: honestly? i dont know any other way, if the action you want to perform is completely independent of model data (like changing the text text color of `EditText` depending of its length) you can do that by simply providing some callbacks in your activity (like `TextWatcher`), but if it has to be dependent of model data some  reference to Activty has to be done

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is create a callback mechanism to trigger a method in your Activity. This will still notify the ViewModel first, but the effect will be the same.

You can create a new interface (or add it inside the ViewModel)

```
public interface ViewModelCallback{
   void ActionCallback();
}
```

In your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewModelCallback
```

In your ViewModel

```
private ArrayList<ViewModelCallback> callbacks = new ArrayList<>();

public void notifyCallbacks(){
  for(ViewModelCallback c : callbacks){
     if(c != null){
         c.ActionCallback
      }
   }
}

public void addCallback(ViewModelCallback c){
     callbacks.add(c);
}
```

Call notifyCallback after your NotifyPropertyChanged().
And don't forget to add your activity as a callback in onCreate

```
viewModel.addCallback(this)
```

You should also remove it in onDestroy.

Comment: thanks,
but i don't want my view model to have a reference to the activity.
it's against the MVVM principals.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, this is just a callback, and it does not use code that is proper to Android. And you will quickly be aware that this kind of trick does not mean your app doesn't follow MVVM principle (just like code behind in WPF. Code behind doesn't automatically mean violation of MVVM)